# Subrings of $M(\mathbb{R})$ and Identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have the following problem.
All matrices of the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a&0\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$ with $a \in \mathbb{R} $

so I understand that this is a subring because it satisfies all the axioms in the book. My question comes in with the identity. My book lists that a ring has an identity if  it contains an element $1_{R}$ such that $a1_{R}=a$ for all $a$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

To try and find the identity I did the following

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
a&0\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix} 1_{R}=\begin{bmatrix}
a&0\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$1_{R}=\begin{bmatrix}
a&0\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
a&0\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$$
but it has no inverse so I thought it had no identity but the back of the book says the identity is 
$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}$ so I'm mostly confused as to why I couldn't get to the answer the way I was trying to do it I do understand why the answer given works any tips or comments on finding the identity more efficiently is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A reader may also take a look at [Nontrivial subring with unity different from the whole ring?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/170953/721644)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The identity of a ring (if it exists) should be an element of the ring. So when you want the identity of the given subring, then you are looking for a matrix $M$ of the form $\begin{bmatrix}m&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ such that
$$AM=MA=A \quad \forall A \in S.$$
Therefore you want
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}m&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix} & =\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\\
\begin{bmatrix}am&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix} & =\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\\
\end{align*}
Thus we want $am=a$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$. This gives $m=1$. You can easily verify that $MA=A$ is satisfied as well.

Comment: Oh..Identity must also be of that form right!it cant be a general matrix ??Please see the above comments!!

Comment: @BAYMAX By definition identity should be a member of the ring under consideration, hence it cannot be any general matrix. Moreover as you can see that $M(\mathbb{R})$ has identity as $I_2$, whereas this subring has the identity $M$.

Comment: Yes, that is a bullet concept right there...