# subring of 2x2 matrices with real entries.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $S = \left\{\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&0\end{bmatrix} :a,b \in \mathbb {R} \right\}$. Prove that the set $S$ is a subring of $M_2 (R)$ with its usual addition and multiplication. Is $S$ a ring with identity? Is it a commutative ring? Describe the units of this ring.

yes this is a subring of $M_2 (R)$, $S$ has an identity but its not the identity in $M_2 (R)$ it is commutative and it has no units. 
Does the fact that the identity is not the same matter?

Comment: You can see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170953/nontrivial-subring-with-unity-different-from-the-whole-ring

Comment: Thats rather complicated for my level of understanding but i believe it says if my ring is a subring of some ring; we only say it has identity if the identity is the same as the original? is this problem arising from my ring having zero divisors with multiplication? groups and subgroups never seem to have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix} \in S$ so S is non empty.

$ \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}c&d\\0&0\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}ac+0&ad+0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ $ac,ad \in \mathbb {R}$ closed under multiplication

$ \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&0\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}c&d\\0&0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}a+c&b+d\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ $(a+c),(b+d) \in \mathbb {R}$ closed under addition

$ \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}c&d\\0&0\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}ac+0&ad+0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$

$ \begin{bmatrix}c&d\\0&0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&0\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}ca+0&cb+0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$

so not a commutative ring.

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} $ is not in S so S has no unity.

Since $ \forall s \in S $ the det(s)=0 nothing is a unit.

Comment: Downvote: subring needs not to have the same unity.