If $R$ is a ring with identity, does any subrng $S$ of $R$ which contains a unit of $R$ also contains the identity of $R$?
If $R$ is a ring with identity, does any subrng $S$ of $R$ which contains a unit of $R$ (an invertible element) also contains the identity of $R$?
Let us say $u$ is a unit in $R$ and $u ∈ S$. Does this mean $1_R$ ∈ S?
I know that in general it is not necessarily true that $1_R = 1_S$ even if $S$ has an identity. However, in my question $S$ contains a unit $u$ from R (it is not supposed that $u$ is a unit in $S$).
Thanks in advance.

There are many counterexamples. A simple one is $R = \mathbb{Z}[X,X^{-1}]$ and $S = X \cdot \mathbb{Z}[X]$. Or even just $R = \mathbb{Q}$ and $S = 2\mathbb{Z}$.

Let $R$ be the field $\Bbb{R}$, so that any non-zero element of $R$ is a unit. Consider the smallest subrng $S$ of $R$ that contains $\pi$. $S$ comprises all real numbers that can be written as polynomials $a_1\pi + a_2\pi^2 + \ldots + a_n\pi^n$, where the $a_i$ are integers. All non-zero elements of $S$ are units in $R$, but $1$ is not in $S$.
This is one of a gazillion examples one can construct by looking at subrngs of fields of characteristic $0$.

I'm not sure what your definition of "subring" is, but I would expect it to be a subset which is closed under all operations: addition and multiplication, but also the zeroary operations (constants) $0$ and $1$. So by definition $S$ must contain $1_R$.
Wikipedia on "subring" seems to agree: "a subring of a ring R is a subset of R that is itself a ring...and that shares the same multiplicative identity as R."

Please don't answer duplicate questions. See here.

@MartinBrandenburg, fair enough, but if I see an upvoted question that's open and new to me, I may be tempted to take a stab at it!

To be precise, you didn't even answer the question. You answered a different one. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170953/nontrivial-subring-with-unity-different-from-the-whole-ring (which has appeared about 5 times already).

Well, the OP's intent was not totally clear, so I took an obvious interpretation and addressed that. Perhaps your edit of the question clarifies their intent, but that doesn't seem clear.

@MartinBrandenburg: your first comment suggests that this question is a duplicate. Is it?

At first I was confused (also by this answer) and misread the question somehow. Hence also my edits to clarify it. The question itself is not obviously a duplicate. I searched a bit, didn't find it, hence also my answer. But the answer here is a duplicate of other answers given elsewhere to a different, duplicate question. Sorry for the confusion!

I have never encountered with "rng" except for Wikipedia; not in my university (METU), not in my books (Gregory T. Lee, Jimmie Gilbert, Dummit&Foote, Hungerford, Gerturde Ehrlich). Removing the letter "i" when there is no identity is a promising idea but I am not sure if it is the mainstream approach. It is not even clear how to read "rng". If there is StackExchange standards for math definitions (like in Wikipedia), please let me know.
